# Can we use "distinguish" to convey "to make something distinguishable"?

Tags: verb-usage

I know about the very common usage of the verb distinguish:

By age of 10, a human being should be able to distinguish bitter from sweet! (self made sentence)

I am wondering if I can reword

> We use two different line styles to make the demand and the production curves distinguishable.

into

> We use two different line styles to distinguish the demand curve from the production curve.

?

Comment: I think you can but that the word **differentiate** better conveys your meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> We use two different line styles to distinguish the demand curve from the production curve.

This is perfect. Your sentence is of the form " . . . distinguish[es] X from Y".

What you are saying is this: *"We use two different line styles to differentiate between the demand curve and the production curve."*

Here are a few examples from Cambridge that are related:

> I sometimes have difficulty distinguishing Spanish from Portuguese.
>
> It's not the beauty so much as the range of his voice that distinguishes him from other tenors.
>
> The male bird displays several characteristics which distinguish him from the female.

*In this chart, we use two different line styles which distinguish the demand curve from the production curve.*